# Как быстро заполнить таблицу 1 000 000 ТЕСТОВЫХ записей?

Tags: mysql, sql

Пусть имеется таблица `tests` с единственным столбцом `title`

```
CREATE TABLE tests (
  title varchar(256) NOT NULL
);
```

Как можно заполнить ее 1 000 000 тестовых записей?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Создадим таблицу `samples` с точно такой же структурой, что и таблица `tests`. Заполним ее 10 тестовыми записями.

```
CREATE TABLE samples (
  title varchar(256) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO
  samples (title)
VALUES
  ('8iRDgsEIq4GmOs32FnHM3b3cH60n3mm8070'), 
  ('UAmsXyrKgApfHMyV2kUrYqLphN99Q7TJSoe'), 
  ('OX1qiFeTigcOTO5JVvgFk7MRDgjgatkTqwL'), 
  ('CT9Kfbplp4QC87G32UIKlkGd31jdjt4qH4f'), 
  ('WsAhjBL5tAgihYZBtX97FNUmEpXavhb4CRw'), 
  ('LwaitJ5dieXyixEmjJXhhqDY8Zg9Tu5ecoV'), 
  ('KpHsnqrcMCpkRxkGNMjEJV0jFaeucPtbLWe'), 
  ('t2GSIDOvW14eMlroAWrRR6xU5DoeNUXY0lD'), 
  ('rSvrEPxR8rcw7QYjXfeNdyf3LpqYNHu3W7a'), 
  ('6liUHPkjnygSatoUB4juZ5TaJZjaxHpR4BL');
```

Для того, чтобы превратить 10 записей из таблицы `samples` в 1 000 000 записей произведем самообъединение таблицы `samples` шесть раз

```
SELECT
  fst.title
FROM
  samples AS fst,
  samples AS snd,
  samples AS thd,
  samples AS fth,
  samples AS fif,
  samples AS sth;
```

Оператор JOIN, который в SQL может быть заменен обычной запятой, осуществляет декартово соединение таблиц, когда каждой записи одной таблицы сопоставляется каждая запись другой таблицы. Таким образом, если в одной таблице 10 записей и в другой таблице 10 записей, результирующая таблица, полученная их соединением через JOIN будет содержать 100 записей. Как нетрудно увидеть

```
10 x 10 x 10 x 10 x 10 x 10 = 1 000 000 записей
```

Если в таблице `samples` будет 100 записей, для получения 1 000 000 записей будет достаточно соединений трех таких таблиц, если в `samples` будет 1000 записей, будет достаточно объединить таблицу саму с собой один раз.

Вставить результат в целевую таблицу `tests` можно при помощи оператора `INSERT ... SELECT ...`

```
INSERT INTO
  tests
SELECT
  fst.title
FROM
  samples AS fst,
  samples AS snd,
  samples AS thd,
  samples AS fth,
  samples AS fif,
  samples AS sth;
```

Comment: Что-то подозрительно... Неужели в mysql это реально работает?

Comment: Да, конечно, вы можете попробовать выполнить последовательность запросов самостоятельно. Я бы не стал его размещать решение, не попробовав его на практике.

Comment: @cheops не могли бы вы пояснить, что такое  "fst, snd, thd, fth, fif, sth;"?

Comment: @koverflow Это псевдонимы таблицы samples. Дело в том, что при самообъединении вы обязаны назначать таблице другие имена, чтобы не было конфликта имен, например, при составлении ON или WHERE -условий, при группировки или сортировке. В данном примере псевдонимы не используются в других частях запроса, тем не менее СУБД обычно требует переименование таблиц в такого рода запросах (по крайней мере MySQL точно), чтобы иметь возможность отличать записи одной копии таблицы samples от другой.

Answer (score 3):

Для MySQL 8+ задача упрощяется - можно воспользоваться рекурсивным CTE ( [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d87a9b06e3aa80690c8024a3de91cdcf)):

```
CREATE TABLE tests (
  title varchar(256) NOT NULL
);

insert into tests 
with recursive cte (n) as (
    select 1 union all
    select 1+n from cte where n<1000
) 
select concat ('title ', t1.n) as title
from cte t1, cte t2;

select title, count(*) over () as numrows 
from tests limit 3;

title     | numrows
----------+-----------
title 1000| 1000000
title 999 | 1000000
title 998 | 1000000
```

Так как кол-во итераций ограничено на макс. 1000, то при превышении будет ошибка:

> Recursive query aborted after 1001 iterations. Try increasing @@cte_max_recursion_depth to a larger value.

Чтобы обойти это ограничение, в примере используется кросс-соединение.