# Инструменты для заполнения БД тестовыми данными

Tags: java, mysql

Есть БД, работа с которой осуществляется Java приложением. БД содержит две таблицы. Первая таблица - пользователи. Состоит из имени, фамилии, даты рождения, пола и отдела. Вторая таблица - отделы. Состоит из номера отдела и названия. Нужно заполнить эту БД тестовыми данными, чтобы в ней было несколько отделов и в каждом отделе несколько десятков пользователей. Данный подойдут типа Имя11, Фамилия11; Имя 21, Фамилия21 и т.д.
С помощью каких инстументов это можно сделать?

Comment: а что такое "тестовые данные" ? как обычно lorem ipsum а изображения lorem pixel

Comment: опишите подробнее или перенесите вопрос на `экстрасенсы.stackoverflow.com`

Comment: @dDevil, поправил вопрос.

Comment: @Geyan, дополнил вопрос.

Comment: Вы указали в метках Java. Какое отношение она имеет к вопросу?

Comment: @D-side, с этой БД взаимодействует Java-приложение.

Comment: @jisecayeyo а как это должно повлиять на ответы? .-.

Comment: @D-side, например, в RoR есть библиотека, позволяющая заполнить БД тестовыми данными.

Comment: @jisecayeyo есть. И я мог бы посоветовать поставить Ruby и написать небольшой скриптик с этой библиотечкой, забивающий базу данными. Это ж всего лишь данные, приложение на Java сможет читать любые данные, которые записаны в MySQL.

Comment: @jisecayeyo берите любой генератор и ....генерируйте.... для заполнения тестовыми данными `java` не нужен.

Answer (score 5):

Например можно воспользоваться онлайн сервисом [Generatedata.com](http://generatedata.com/) или [mockaroo.com](https://www.mockaroo.com/)

Надо всего лишь указать тип столбцов, их имена и в каком формате сделать экспорт (SQLs, HTML, Excel, XML, CSV).

Пример работы *Generatedata*:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сгенерирует:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Datagenerator](http://www.dominicgiles.com/datagenerator.html) и [Test Data Generator For MySQL Databases](http://datanamic.com/datagenerator-for-mysql/index.html) - программы, которые помогут сгенерировать данные.

Также можно воспользоваться способом с [самообъединением таблиц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/541078/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-1-000-000-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9) на нашем любимом ruSO. Правда данные тут будут копироваться и не будут сильно уникальными для каждой строки (в отличие от данных, сгенерированных через утилиты, описанные выше)